# The type WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just migrate to spring mvc version `5.0.1.RELEASE` but suddenly in eclipse STS WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is marked as deprecated

```
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        // to serve static .html pages...
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/");
    }
  ....
  }
```

How can i remove this!

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Since Spring 5 you just need to implement the interface `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

This is because Java 8 introduced default methods on interfaces which cover the functionality of the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class

See here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html

Comment: What if I had `super.configureMessageConverters(converters)` how can now i translate this code? Now there's is no `super` to refer to.

Comment: @yami You just call configureMessageConverters(converters) this will run the default method defined on the interface

Comment: @Plog, @Yami: Doing as suggested produces a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, because omitting the `.super` starts a recursive, never ending call loop.

Comment: Adding converters to the list, turns off default converter registration. By calling super.configureMessageConverters(converters) first you probably want to keep the default converter. To simply add a converter without impacting default registration, consider using the method `extendMessageConverters(java.util.List)` (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#extendMessageConverters-java.util.List-) instead.

Comment: @ThirstForKnowledge yeah, cause of that i just deleted this line. I did not want to have infinite loop.

Comment: @ThirstForKnowledge Oh this is my bad. The way you should call a super default method on an interface is: WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureMessageConverters(converters)

Answer (score 11):

I have been working on Swagger equivalent documentation library called `Springfox` nowadays and I found that in the Spring 5.0.8 (running at present), interface `WebMvcConfigurer` has been implemented by class `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class which we can directly extend.

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport { }
```

And this is how I have used it for setting my resource handling mechanism as follows -

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spring every request will go through the **DispatcherServlet**. To avoid Static file request through DispatcherServlet(Front contoller) we configure [MVC Static content](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources).

**Spring 3.1.** introduced the ResourceHandlerRegistry to configure ResourceHttpRequestHandlers for serving static resources from the classpath, the WAR, or the file system. We can configure the ResourceHandlerRegistry programmatically inside our web context configuration class.

> - we have added the **`/js/**`** pattern to the ResourceHandler, lets include the `foo.js` resource located in the **`webapp/js/`** directory
> - we have added the **`/resources/static/**`** pattern to the ResourceHandler, lets include the `foo.html` resource located in the **`webapp/resources/`** directory

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class StaticResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("WebMvcConfigurer - addResourceHandlers() function get loaded...");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");

        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/js/")
            .setCachePeriod(3600)
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver())
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

**XML Configuration**

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/staticFiles/path/**" location="/staticFilesFolder/js/"
                 cache-period="60"/>
```

**Spring Boot [MVC Static Content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)** if the file is located in the WAR’s **webapp/resources** folder.

```java
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/static/**
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer`

With Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE (Spring Framework 5.1.6.RELEASE), do like this

```
package vn.bkit;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter; // Deprecated.
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```